# Calculating distance to a fixed point on a map

Tags: gps, distance, latitude-longitude

I have a point with latitude 40.7127837 and longitude -74.00594130000002

I have imagined this point on a plane like this

[image]

Latitudes run from West to East and longitudes run from North to South

Can i use a latitude only or longitude only to know how far an object is from the value of the longitude or latitude that i know?.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need both coordinates to calculate the distance. For one coordinate further need to know the angle\azimuth.